# Java hexadecimal RegExp

Tags: java, regex

I have a hexadecimal string, I looking for a pattern to use for search an Hexadecimal number of 2 digits in a specific range.
I know that if a use a pattern like "B[0-9A-F]" i find all the value between B0 and BF, but if I need to search a range like BF-C1 so all the values BF C0 and C1 what kind of pattern can I use?

Thanks to all!

Comment: Is it really necessary to use a regex? Why not convert and do a range compare?

Comment: Why use regexes for that? You can use `Integer.parseInt()` with a base 16 and test the value range from the parsed integer

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Comment: I need regexp for that... I know that there are other way to solve this, but a search for a pattern.

Comment: You can use a simple regex for matching the pattern, but for range validation, regex is not the correct tool.  use `[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]` to find your hex values, then the `Integer.parseInt()` to validate the range; otherwise you're going to be getting in to regexes which look like `0[9A-F]|[A-E][0-9A-F]|F[0-1]` and calculating the edge cases is going to be far less efficient than simply doing the two stage operation.

Answer (score 0):

There are just 3 values there.
You can use: `BF|C0|C1`
You can also do: `BF|C[01]`

Comment: I know, I only write an example, I can also write a range in 09-F1, if you prefer. Thanks for the reply!